# MongoDB Geospacial Query on MultiPolygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I've been reading through mongo's docs on geospacial querying, and have things working well for singl Polygon types but am having trouble with MultiPolygon. What I want to do is essentially this:

Given a MultiPolygon outlining areas of exclusion:

```
{
    "type" : "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -117.873730659485, 
                    33.6152089844919
                ], 
                [ 
                    -117.873065471649, 
                    33.615048159758
                ], 
                [ 
                    -117.873044013977, 
                    33.614690770386
                ], 
                [ 
                    -117.873666286469, 
                    33.6146729008785
                ], 
                [ 
                    -117.873730659485, 
                    33.6152089844919
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I simply want to be able to pass in a `Point` to see if it is excluded. I've tried `$geoIntersects` just to see if it even can determine if a `Point` is included or not, but that doesn't work. In the end, I want to check that a point is *not* included within the exclusion list, but the query is simpler without the additional `$not` operator... Here's what I've been trying:

```
var geoPoint = {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-117.8731230, 33.6150696]};
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {$match: {'exclusionsPolygons': {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: geoPoint}}}}
]);
```

Note that if I do the same exact thing with a `GeoJSON` type of `Polygon` then it works just fine:

Given this single polygon:

```
{
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                -117.8711744, 
                33.6129677
            ], 
            [ 
                -117.8751744, 
                33.6129677
            ], 
            [ 
                -117.874444839148, 
                33.6162171973226
            ], 
            [ 
                -117.87287399259, 
                33.6172714730352
            ], 
            [ 
                -117.871410434393, 
                33.6165209730032
            ], 
            [ 
                -117.8711744, 
                33.6129677
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

This query works just find and returns the item(s) whose singular polygon contains the point:

```
var geoPoint = {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-117.8731230, 33.6150696]};
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {$match: {'singularPolygon': {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: geoPoint}}}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, it turns out the result set was right and I was wrong...

I was using the areas of interest on the map to get addresses to try to query against. One such place was, I thought, in an exclusion polygon:

[image: Exclusion Polygon]

However, once I made the polygon larger the result set started coming back as I expected it to... So, I reset the polygon and double-checked the map content, finding that if I zoom in further the area of interest was actually excluded from the polygon as there are multiple areas of interest contained:

[image: Exclusion Polygon - Zoomed]

Whoops - my bad :)

Comment: Just a note: don't forget that most of MongoDB's Geo functions follows the curvature of the earth, which could lead to unexpected situation (what looks like a straight line might curve due to the earth surface). If you need to confirm your geometries, you can use http://geodndmap.mongodb.com. Just drag and drop your geometries on the map.